# How to modify WCF Soap Message Body Response

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

I have the following WCF service which accepts and SOAP Message and I'm wanting it to return a SOAP Message response.

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {          
       [OperationContract(Action = "HotelAvailRQ", ReplyAction = "HotelAvailRQResponse")]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
       Message HotelAvailRQ(Message message);       
    }

    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
       public Message HotelAvailRQ(Message message)
       {
           return ProcessMessage<OTA_HotelAvailRQ>(message);
       }

       public Message ProcessMessage<T>(Message message)
       {
           MessageBuffer buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(8192);

           // Get a copy of the original message. This will be used to read and extract the body.
           Message msgCopy = buffer.CreateMessage();

           // Take another copy of the same message. This will be used to return to the service. Returning an identical message forms part of the acknowledgement in this case.
           Message returnMsg = buffer.CreateMessage();

           XElement body = XElement.Parse(msgCopy.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadOuterXml());
           var instance = Deserialize<T>(body, "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05");

           MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(T).GetMethod("Process");
           object document = methodInfo.Invoke(instance, null);

           return returnMsg;

       }

       private static T Deserialize<T>(XElement xElement, string nameSpace)
       {
           using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xElement.ToString())))
           {
               XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), nameSpace);
               return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
           }
       }

       private static string Serialize(object obj)
       {
           using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
           {
               XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
               xs.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);
               return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
           }
       }
   }  

   public partial class OTA_HotelAvailRQ
   {
       public static object Process()
       {
           try
           {
               OTA_HotelAvailRQ hotelAvailRQ = new OTA_HotelAvailRQ();
               //Do some stuff and return back new object
               return hotelAvailRQ ;
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {            
               return new OTA_HotelAvailRS(); //TODO Should be fault exception...
           }
       }
   }
```

Do I need to modify the incoming SOAP message, with my Body response ?  If so, how do I modify the response, or create a new SOAP message response ?

UPDATE:

I tried what @popo suggested, which was

```
   var respObj = new object(); //resposneObjBody
   var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
   {
       IgnoreWhitespace = true
   };

   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
       XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(respObj.GetType());
       xs.Serialize(ms, respObj);
       ms.Position = 0; '<< Added
       var reader = XmlReader.Create(ms, settings);
       var newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, msgCopy.Version);
       newMessage.Headers.Clear();
       newMessage.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(msgCopy.Headers);
   }
```

But had to add `ms.Position = 0;` because I was getting the exception `Root element is missing`

However, the problem I have now is Fault exception `Unrecognized message version.`  Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: I would think that you could create a new message, use the message version, from original message, copy headers from original message, and add the content from you response, that might be easier than trying to modify your request message. There are multiple overloads to create a message. `Message.CreateMessage(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will be helpful or not, but if not I will delete the answer, maybe someone else will have something more enlightening. This is modified version of some code I use in a message inspector to manipulate a message and pass it on to the operation. 
(below is not tested):

```
    var respObj = new object(); //resposneObjBody you have to define this object type added just for filler
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
    {
        IgnoreWhitespace = true
    };

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(respObj.GetType());
            xs.Serialize(ms, respObj);
            ms.Position = 0; 
            var reader = XmlReader.Create(ms, settings);
            var newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(msgCopy.Version, null, reader); // action is null, but you may want to put your reply action here
            newMessage.Headers.Clear(); //you may not need this either
            newMessage.Headers.CopyHeadersFrom(msgCopy.Headers); //you may not need this either
            newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(msgCopy.Properties); //optional??
    }
```

Comment: I updated my question with your suggestion, but am getting the exception 'Unrecognized message version.' ? Any ideas, since we are using the original message version

Comment: @Tommassiov I updated my answer, I think that will work for you. I am not sure your reply message actually needs the headers and properties from your original message, likely not. Hope it helps :)